# How to check if a another user is on the same or lower level in the company hierarchy?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory, user-profile

I've got this:

```
UserProfile prof = getUserProfile(properties.CurrentUserId);
UserProfile toCheck = getUserProfile(anotherUsersId);
```

"prof" user must be on a higher or on the same level as "toCheck" user. If "toCheck" is on a lower level he/she must be on the same branch of the hierarchy tree. If they are on the same level, their manager must be the same.

Is there an easy way to check this?

Comment: what defines the "level" in your case?

Comment: A manager of a user is 1 level higher. There is only one ubermanager in the company. So the hierarchy tree is like a real tree, upside down.

Comment: I think this is using the Sharepoint UserProfile class (namespace Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles), I've no experience with it myself. If that's not the case then Vili needs to post the code for their UserProfile class.

Comment: Yes, this is a SharePoint class.

Comment: Are you using the Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles namespace or the legacy Microsoft.Sharepoint.Portal namespace?

Comment: I am using the Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles namespace. It has a Colleagues property which has an IsColleague method. Don't know what this does because I nowhere could find Microsoft's definition to the word "colleague". In my country the boss and an employee can be colleagues. But this is not grammar, this is programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few methods that should help you here:

- [GetPeers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.getpeers.aspx)
- [GetManagers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.getmanagers.aspx)
- [GetDirectReports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.getdirectreports.aspx)

There is no "easy way" that I've found but you can write your own helper classes that use these methods, traverse the user profiles, and find the information you need.

As an aside: "Colleagues" is not related to this. They are a list of people that, with a complete My Site implementation, users can manage themselves.

Comment: GetManager was the solution. But it wasn't an easy way. :) (Nontrivial (for me)) recursion were needed.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo code:

```
function compare(manager, toCheck, prof) 
{
    toManager=toCheck.manager;
    if (toManager!=null)
    {
        if (manager==tomanager || prof==tomanager)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return compare("", tomanager, prof);
        }
    }
    else // he/she is the boss
    {
        return false;
    }

}

...

if (prof.manager!=null)
{
    compare(prof.manager, toCheck, prof);
}
else  // he/she is the boss
{
    return true;
}
```